# How to set minimum date for "ToDate" on datepicker as per the "FromDate" i chosed on another datepicker

Tags: java, android, android-datepicker

In brief, I have two date pickers (From, To). Where I choose "FromDate" and "ToDate" up to the current date.

If I choose 2019-04-04 to "FromDate" and when I choose "ToDate", it should hide the dates which are before "FromDate". How can I achieve this?

```
mFromEditTextBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        DatePickerDialog fromPicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        fromPicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000);
        fromPicker.show();

        clickedView = (EditText) v;
    }
});

mToEditTextBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        DatePickerDialog toPicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        toPicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000);
        toPicker.show();
        clickedView = (EditText) v;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a minimum date for toDate picker

```
mToEditTextBox.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        DatePickerDialog toPicker = new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), date, myCalendar
                .get(Calendar.YEAR), myCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH),
                myCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        //set min date
        Date fromDate = parseFromDate();
        if (fromDate != null){
            toPicker.getDatePicker().setMinDate(fromDate.getTime());
        }

        toPicker.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(System.currentTimeMillis()-1000);
        toPicker.show();
        clickedView = (EditText) v;
    }
});

// returns date selected in mFromEditTextBox
private Date parseFromDate(){
    try{
        SimpleDateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("date format you used");
        return f.parse(mFromEditTextBox.getText().toString());
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        // from date is not selected
        // alert user to select from date
        return null;
    }
}
```

[DatePicker](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/DatePicker.html#setMinDate(long))

Hope this helps!

Comment: i got "cannot resolve symbol parseDate" for return f.parseDate(mFromEditTextBox.getText().toString());
I tried making it as parse but its not working as required

Comment: And i am getting the selected "FromDate" in the "ToDate" datepicker but the before dates are not getting disabled

Comment: @Abhishek actually it's not parseDate, just parse. I'll update the answer

Comment: kindly refer my other comment above

Comment: Are you sure that parseFromDate returns a date?

Comment: yes it is returning a date, once the date is chosed. But in my case i am displaying current date on page load

Comment: Does it returns current date if from date is not selected?

Comment: Not sure why the solution is not working, BTW there is an opensource alternative to android date picker dialog. just have a look at https://github.com/square/android-times-square